# Including file to separate content and minimize data

Tags: asp.net, include

I've just started learning ASP.Net but I've come across something that I don't know how it works. Say I have a "main page" that looks the same but depending on what GET value "page" says I should try loading a certain page without changing the main content. I have an index.aspx and whenever I goto index.aspx?page=login, it should try to load login.aspx.

Sure it works, but it writes out the ASP.Net code and not processing it. Not like PHP's include().

What I've tried is: Response.WriteFile() without no luck...

This is because, I have an index.aspx with an runat server id of Content and whatever the page I'm suppose to load is going to go there. So I don't have to recreate every page I make.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should look at Master Pages. ASP.NET master pages allow you to create a consistent layout for the pages in your application.

A single master page defines the look and feel and standard behavior that you want for all of the pages (or a group of pages) in your application.

You can then create individual content pages that contain the content you want to display. When users request the content pages, they merge with the master page to produce output that combines the layout of the master page with the content from the content page.

[ASP.NET Master Pages - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx)